# What does “Espace design” mean?

Tags: sens

I'm  having trouble figuring out what “*espace design*” means since “designer space” doesn't really mean much in English.

To provide a bit more context, the article is about a fashion exhibition that takes place or is set up in “*un espace design*”.

Any help would be much appreciated.

One idea I've come up with is “boutique space”

Comment: fashion show space...I never heard of a fashion exhibition....unless it's a museum.

Answer (score 7):

The obvious English appearance of the word *design* gives it a distinctive *recherché* feeling that *design* in English just doesn't have. *Designer* used as an adjective comes a lot closer.

In this context, *espace* is an exhibition hall, typically a building comprising a large room with temporary booths that people wander around. *Designer space* is actually not far from the mark, but doesn't quite sound right in English. *Designer hall*? *Designer exhibit*?

[This article about an “espace design” in Montréal](http://societeperrier.com/montreal/articles/upcoming-event-semaine-de-la-mode-de-montreal) translates the expression with *Designer studio*.

Answer (score 4):

As I understand it, it seems that "un espace design" here means a place reserved for Design exhibitions, it generally is placed in a store where consumers can look at new and innovating products.

Comment: ah! how does the simple "exhibit" sound to you?

Answer (score 3):

*Design exhibit area* should do it.

Or maybe the longer alternative *design-themed exhibition space*

Answer (score 2):

In that context, the author just wants to emphasize that the exhibition place is decorated in a modern and creative way, what is familiarly called "design" in french.
Like "un meuble design", "une voiture design".

It just means that the particular object which is "design", express creativity/modernity